# Controlling the text size in the canvas (textarea)

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I want to create a canvas that displays text from textarea.
I have a problem with controlling the size of the text in textarea.
In other words, I want the user to choose the size of the text then write it in the text area which in turn will be displayed on the canvas once the button is clicked.

I tried this code but there is a problem i do not what is it.
Here is a sample of the code:

```
<script>
var y = 30;
function pasteText()
{

Text=document.getElementById('textarea').value;
var x = 30;
var lineheight = 15;
var lines = Text.split('\n');

$("#clr2 font").click(function (){
context.fillStyle=$(this).css("color");
});

$("#clr3 font").click(function (){
context.font=$(this).css("font-size")+ "Arial";
});

for (var i = 0; i<lines.length; i++)


    context.fillText(lines[i], x, y + (i*lineheight) );
    y+=38;
}


</script>
<body>

<canvas class="canvas" id="canvas" width="600" height="200" style="border:1px solid"> </canvas>

<font id="clr3">
<font style="font-size:9pt;"> Small</font>
<font style="font-size:16pt;"> Medium</font>
<font style="font-size:24pt;"> Large</font>
</font>


 <textarea name="textarea" cols="72" rows="6" id="textarea" value="Type the text here" ></textarea>
 <input  type="button" name="paste" value="Paste on the canvas" onClick="pasteText()"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var container = layer2.parentNode;

    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Any help pleaaaaaaaaaaaaase:-(

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a lot of problems in your code, some that pop immediately:

- The `for` loop code in not enclosed in braces `{  }`
- The click handlers are defined inside the `pasteText` function and thus will only be registered after the user clicked the paste text button.
- the `<font>` tags are not standart tags and some browsers, especially IE won't like it.

#### update:

Is it possible that what's missing is a space between the font size and the font face? try to add a space before the `Arial`:

```
context.font=$(this).css("font-size")+ " Arial";
```

Comment: Thanx for your reply. Actually the for loop works well and the font tag also works in firefox. When the user clicks on paste button the text will be displayed in the canvas that what i want my program to do. The problem i have is in the size, when i clicked on for example Large the canvas displays the default size which i don't want it. Any help pleaaaaaaaaaaaaase

Comment: added another possible fix, if this won't help try to construct your code in a jsfiddle and it'll be easier for everyone to debug it there.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that the problem is in context.font

because context.font accepts the size and the family of the font.

I am not sure if what I wrote in my code is the correct syntax
context.font=$(this).css("font-size")+ "Arial";

Comment: Thanks Varaint it works the problem was in the space before "Arial".